# Magento 2 : Insert image or select image not load -blank page

Tags: magento2.4, image-upload, wysiwyg, tinymce

Do not be tired
I noticed today that when I want to put a photo in the product and click on the image button, the page does not open and a white page opens.
Can you advise where the problem could be?

[image]

console error

Content Security Policy: Interpreting unsafe-inline as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use ‘unsafe-inline’ (wrapped in single quotes).
Content Security Policy: This site (https://----.com) has a Report-Only policy without a report URI. CSP will not block and cannot report violations of this policy.
This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”.     ef7a997b7aa6f6b8287662ad94596a41a28d66e4a47d04eb4c6e022fb70a9ddc
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 6
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1 jquery-migrate.min.js:5:165
This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/performance/scroll-linked_effects.html for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!     ef7a997b7aa6f6b8287662ad94596a41a28d66e4a47d04eb4c6e022fb70a9ddc
Content Security Policy: Interpreting https://unsafe-inline as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use ‘unsafe-inline’ (wrapped in single quotes).
Content Security Policy: This site (https://---.com) has a Report-Only policy without a report URI. CSP will not block and cannot report violations of this policy.
Content Security Policy: Interpreting https://unsafe-inline as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use ‘unsafe-inline’ (wrapped in single quotes).
Content Security Policy: This site (https://---.com) has a Report-Only policy without a report URI. CSP will not block and cannot report violations of this policy.
Content Security Policy: Interpreting https://unsafe-inline as a hostname, not a keyword. If you intended this to be a keyword, use ‘unsafe-inline’ (wrapped in single quotes).
Content Security Policy: This site (https://---.com) has a Report-Only policy without a report URI. CSP will not block and cannot report violations of this policy.
MouseEvent.mozPressure is deprecated. Use PointerEvent.pressure instead.

screen shot
[image]

Comment: Hi there, please help us more to debug this issue by sharing if there is any console error in your browser's dev tools and observe the network tab when u trigger this action whether the URL returns other than 200, and share the response if it is unusual.Thanks.

Comment: @BharathKumarJ Hi, add error console

Comment: Thanks, better can you share the screenshots instead? And is this a fresh magento installation or a client project which has 3rd party modules and themes and can i know what browser are you using ?

Comment: @BharathKumarJ Thanks, i used magento 2.4.3 in vps

Comment: Okay i hop the issue is resolved , have a nice day.

Comment: @BharathKumarJ I asked you for help, I did not ask you to wish me success